# Magento 2. 2 Mail template can not be translated

Tags: magento2.2, localisation, locale

I am offering English and Japanese in Magento 2 project.

We respond to customer's inquiries about products.

I want to make the mail template of that module correspond to Japanese, but it is not translated.

[image]

Please tell me how to resolve.